# Is it possible to color code certain rows in a chart?

Tags: excel

I have the following data

```
3/2/16  5
3/3/16  1
3/4/16  1
3/8/16  1
3/9/16  1
3/10/16 2
3/11/16 6
```

and I get the following chart
[image]

In the chart, I want to highlight the dates 3/8/16, 3/9/16, 3/10/16 and 3/11/16.
Is it possible to do that ? I want to distinguish between dates prior to 3/8 and dates after 3/8 and hence thought highlighting in the chart would show the distinction.

Comment: you might be able to do it with a little trickery.  if you copy you column of value to the right and then delete the non highlighted value (keep the cell just delete the contents), then go to your first column and delete the content of the cells you want highlighted.  Then add a series to your graph and select the second column.  Because its a different series you can colour it independently.  You may need to change your chart type though.

Comment: Awesome Forward. Works great.

Answer (score 0):

Break your data into two separate series.

- Copy the column of values to an adjacent column.
- Delete the cells you do not want highlighted from the adjacent column.
- Delete the cells you do want highlighted from the original column.
- Add new series to your graph.
- Colour series fill to your choosing.
- Set series overlap and width to 0

Proof of Concept

[image: POF]

Comment: Hi Forward, My table is a pivot report. In a pivot report, I can copy the column values to the adjacent column but when I delete the cells for the highlighted data, it says "cannot change this part of the pivotttable report". Is there a way around it ?

Comment: you might be able to link cells in an unused column to the cells of your pivot report. and then use those new cells as your series.  I do not use Pivot stuff so I am not sure what the best approach is.  You might also be able to copy and paste special and past values.  depends on how often you plan on reusing this spreadsheet.